# CSS Table - First row and first column sticky

Tags: html, css

I've been working with a CSS code for some time, and I can't figure out what I'm doing incorrectly. I've tried multiple methods to achieve this result, no success. Please help!!

**Desired result:** The table 'contents' (indicated by red/white/gray) to be scrollable, z index of 1. The first column and first row (indicated by orange) to be sticky, z index of 2. The 'empty box' (indicated by purple) to be stationary and unmoving, z index of 3. Essentially, the first column/first row should never be able to go on top of the purple.

This is a problem, the orange should be sliding behind the purple when scrolling.
[image: this is a problem, should not happen.]

**Codepin:** https://codepen.io/dansbyt/pen/abJrWeL?editors=1100

```css
.gradebook {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px; left: 0;
  width: 100vw; height: calc(100vh - 126px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  box-sizing: border-box;}

/* Table styling*/
table {
  overflow: scroll;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  overflow-x: auto;}

/* Sticky Support */
tbody th {position: -webkit-sticky; position: sticky; left: 0; z-index: 1; background-color: orange !important}
thead th {position: -webkit-sticky; position: sticky; top: 0; z-index: 2;  background-color: orange !important}
thead th:first-child {left: 0; z-index: 1;}

/* Table heading styling */
thead th {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: gray}

th.average {
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid gray;}
th.assign{
  height: 60px; width: 100px;
  top: 0; z-index: 2;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: white;}

th.white {background-color: PURPLE !important; z-index: 3;}
table .duedate {font-size: 14px; margin-bottom: 8px}
table .title {font-size: 18px; color: #5B7042}

/* Table data styling */
td, tbody th:not(.white) {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: white}
td.average, th.average {
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #F2F2F2}
td.late{background-color: #EA5D6B}

td input {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px; margin: 0;
  width: 80%;
  border: none;}
  input.stone{color: gray}

/* Student Name styling */
.student {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: left !important;
  padding: 6px;}

.pic{
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  clip-path: circle();
  margin-left: 6px;
  margin-right: 12px;}

/* ------------{CONTROLS}------------ */
.controls {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px; left: 0;
  width: 100vw; height: 56px;
  border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD}
```

```html
<div class='gradebook'>
  <table>
<thead>
  <th class='white' rowspan='2' colspan='2'>A</th>
  <tr>
    <th class='assign'>
            <div class='duedate'>Jun 20</div>
            <div class='title'>Worksheet</div>
          </th>
    <th class='assign'>
            <div class='duedate'>Jun 20</div>
            <div class='title'>Worksheet</div>
          </th>
    <th class='assign'>
            <div class='duedate'>Jun 20</div>
            <div class='title'>Worksheet</div>
          </th>
    <th class='assign'>
            <div class='duedate'>Jun 20</div>
            <div class='title'>Worksheet</div>
          </th>
    <th class='assign'>
            <div class='duedate'>Jun 20</div>
            <div class='title'>Worksheet</div>
          </th>
    <th class='assign'>
            <div class='duedate'>Jun 20</div>
            <div class='title'>Worksheet</div>
          </th>
    <th class='assign'>
            <div class='duedate'>Jun 20</div>
            <div class='title'>Worksheet</div>
          </th>
    <th class='assign'>
            <div class='duedate'>Jun 20</div>
            <div class='title'>Worksheet</div>
          </th>
    <th class='assign'>
            <div class='duedate'>Jun 20</div>
            <div class='title'>Worksheet</div>
          </th>
    <th class='assign'>
            <div class='duedate'>Jun 20</div>
            <div class='title'>Worksheet</div>
          </th>
    <th class='assign'>
            <div class='duedate'>Jun 20</div>
            <div class='title'>Worksheet</div>
          </th>
    <th class='assign'>
            <div class='duedate'>Jun 20</div>
            <div class='title'>Worksheet</div>
          </th>
    <th class='assign'>
            <div class='duedate'>Jun 20</div>
            <div class='title'>Worksheet</div>
          </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='white'></td>
    <td class='white'></td>
    <td class='average'>-</td>
    <td class='average'>-</td>
    <td class='average'>-</td>
    <td class='average'>-</td>
    <td class='average'>-</td>
    <td class='average'>-</td>
    <td class='average'>-</td>
    <td class='average'>-</td>
    <td class='average'>-</td>
    <td class='average'>-</td>
    <td class='average'>-</td>
    <td class='average'>-</td>
    <td class='average'>-</td>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr><th class='student'><img class='pic' src=''><span>Student</span></th><td class='average'>XX%</td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td></tr>
  <tr><th class='student'><img class='pic' src=''><span>Student</span></th><td class='average'>XX%</td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td></tr>
  <tr><th class='student'><img class='pic' src=''><span>Student</span></th><td class='average'>XX%</td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td></tr>
  <tr><th class='student'><img class='pic' src=''><span>Student</span></th><td class='average'>XX%</td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td></tr>
  <tr><th class='student'><img class='pic' src=''><span>Student</span></th><td class='average'>XX%</td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td></tr>
  <tr><th class='student'><img class='pic' src=''><span>Student</span></th><td class='average'>XX%</td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td></tr>
  <tr><th class='student'><img class='pic' src=''><span>Student</span></th><td class='average'>XX%</td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td></tr>
  <tr><th class='student'><img class='pic' src=''><span>Student</span></th><td class='average'>XX%</td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td></tr>
  <tr><th class='student'><img class='pic' src=''><span>Student</span></th><td class='average'>XX%</td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td></tr>
  <tr><th class='student'><img class='pic' src=''><span>Student</span></th><td class='average'>XX%</td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td></tr>
  <tr><th class='student'><img class='pic' src=''><span>Student</span></th><td class='average'>XX%</td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td></tr>
  <tr><th class='student'><img class='pic' src=''><span>Student</span></th><td class='average'>XX%</td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td></tr>
  <tr><th class='student'><img class='pic' src=''><span>Student</span></th><td class='average'>XX%</td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td></tr>  
</tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `tbody > th` and `thead > th` shares the same z-index value:

```
tbody th {
   ...
   z-index: 1;
}

thead th:first-child {
   ...
   z-index: 1;
}
```

When the document reads `tbody > th` it will then overlaps `thead > th`. So giving the `thead > th` a `position: sticky` is enough for it to scroll along within the container and leaving `tbody > th` underneath  it like so:

```
tbody th {
  background-color: orange !important;
/*   z-index: 1; */
}

thead th {
  position: -webkit-sticky; 
  position: sticky; 
  top: 0; 
/*   z-index: 2;   */
  background-color: orange !important
}

/* thead th:first-child { ...; z-index: 1; } */
```

```css
/* ------------{GRADEBOOK}------------ */
.gradebook {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px; left: 0;
  width: 100vw; height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  box-sizing: border-box;}

/* Table styling*/
table {
  overflow: scroll;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  overflow-x: auto;}

/* Sticky Support */
tbody th {position: -webkit-sticky; position: sticky; left: 0; background-color: orange !important}
thead th {position: -webkit-sticky; position: sticky; top: 0; left: 0;  background-color: orange !important}

/* Table heading styling */
thead th {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: gray}

th.average {
  width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid gray;}
th.assign{
  height: 60px; width: 100px;
  top: 0; z-index: 2;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: white;}

th.white {background-color: PURPLE !important; z-index: 3;}
table .duedate {font-size: 14px; margin-bottom: 8px}
table .title {font-size: 18px; color: #5B7042}

/* Table data styling */
td, tbody th:not(.white) {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background-color: white}
td.average, th.average {
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #F2F2F2}
td.late{background-color: #EA5D6B}

td input {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 4px; margin: 0;
  width: 80%;
  border: none;}
  input.stone{color: gray}

/* Student Name styling */
.student {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: left !important;
  padding: 6px;}

.pic{
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 25px;
  clip-path: circle();
  margin-left: 6px;
  margin-right: 12px;}

/* ------------{CONTROLS}------------ */
.controls {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px; left: 0;
  width: 100vw; height: 56px;
  border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD}
```

```html
<div class='gradebook'>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th class='white' rowspan='2' colspan='2'>A</th>
      <tr>
        <th class='assign'>
                <div class='duedate'>Jun 20</div>
                <div class='title'>Worksheet</div>
              </th>
        <th class='assign'>
                <div class='duedate'>Jun 20</div>
                <div class='title'>Worksheet</div>
              </th>
        <th class='assign'>
                <div class='duedate'>Jun 20</div>
                <div class='title'>Worksheet</div>
              </th>
        <th class='assign'>
                <div class='duedate'>Jun 20</div>
                <div class='title'>Worksheet</div>
              </th>
        <th class='assign'>
                <div class='duedate'>Jun 20</div>
                <div class='title'>Worksheet</div>
              </th>
        <th class='assign'>
                <div class='duedate'>Jun 20</div>
                <div class='title'>Worksheet</div>
              </th>
        <th class='assign'>
                <div class='duedate'>Jun 20</div>
                <div class='title'>Worksheet</div>
              </th>
        <th class='assign'>
                <div class='duedate'>Jun 20</div>
                <div class='title'>Worksheet</div>
              </th>
        <th class='assign'>
                <div class='duedate'>Jun 20</div>
                <div class='title'>Worksheet</div>
              </th>
        <th class='assign'>
                <div class='duedate'>Jun 20</div>
                <div class='title'>Worksheet</div>
              </th>
        <th class='assign'>
                <div class='duedate'>Jun 20</div>
                <div class='title'>Worksheet</div>
              </th>
        <th class='assign'>
                <div class='duedate'>Jun 20</div>
                <div class='title'>Worksheet</div>
              </th>
        <th class='assign'>
                <div class='duedate'>Jun 20</div>
                <div class='title'>Worksheet</div>
              </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='white'></td>
        <td class='white'></td>
        <td class='average'>-</td>
        <td class='average'>-</td>
        <td class='average'>-</td>
        <td class='average'>-</td>
        <td class='average'>-</td>
        <td class='average'>-</td>
        <td class='average'>-</td>
        <td class='average'>-</td>
        <td class='average'>-</td>
        <td class='average'>-</td>
        <td class='average'>-</td>
        <td class='average'>-</td>
        <td class='average'>-</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><th class='student'><img class='pic' src=''><span>Student</span></th><td class='average'>XX%</td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td></tr>
      <tr><th class='student'><img class='pic' src=''><span>Student</span></th><td class='average'>XX%</td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td></tr>
      <tr><th class='student'><img class='pic' src=''><span>Student</span></th><td class='average'>XX%</td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td></tr>
      <tr><th class='student'><img class='pic' src=''><span>Student</span></th><td class='average'>XX%</td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td></tr>
      <tr><th class='student'><img class='pic' src=''><span>Student</span></th><td class='average'>XX%</td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td></tr>
      <tr><th class='student'><img class='pic' src=''><span>Student</span></th><td class='average'>XX%</td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td></tr>
      <tr><th class='student'><img class='pic' src=''><span>Student</span></th><td class='average'>XX%</td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td></tr>
      <tr><th class='student'><img class='pic' src=''><span>Student</span></th><td class='average'>XX%</td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td></tr>
      <tr><th class='student'><img class='pic' src=''><span>Student</span></th><td class='average'>XX%</td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td></tr>
      <tr><th class='student'><img class='pic' src=''><span>Student</span></th><td class='average'>XX%</td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td></tr>
      <tr><th class='student'><img class='pic' src=''><span>Student</span></th><td class='average'>XX%</td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td></tr>
      <tr><th class='student'><img class='pic' src=''><span>Student</span></th><td class='average'>XX%</td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td></tr>
      <tr><th class='student'><img class='pic' src=''><span>Student</span></th><td class='average'>XX%</td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td><td class='late'><input class='stone' type='text' value=''></td></tr>  
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: That fixes the first column from acting funky, but the first row is still not sliding behind the purple. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Did you make more changes from your base code? I just opened your codeopen link and edited it as I suggested and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I checked the code, but the purple box moves away as you scroll horizontally. Ideally, the purple box would never move no matter what direction you scroll. Any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Yup just put `left: 0;` on that element. I have updated my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Set `z-index:2` in `thead th:first-child`

Comment: That fixes the first column from acting funky, but the first row is still not sliding behind the purple. How can I accomplish this?